# Big O complexity of simple for not always linear?

Tags: theory, complexity-theory, big-o

I'm sure most of you know that a nested loop has O(n^2) complexity if the function input size is n

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
...
}
}
```

I think that this is similar, by a analogous argument, but i'm not sure can anyone confirm?

```
for(int i = 0, max = n*n; i < max; i++{
...
}
```

If so i guess that there is some kinds of code whose big O mapping is not immediately obvious besides recursion and subroutines.

Comment: What is a "simple for" anyway?

Comment: Imagine it does a sum, a O(1) constant operation.

Comment: "Simple "for" loop", I presume. Need a definition for simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your basic simple loop is always O(m) where m is the upper bound on the iterations.  But your m is really n*n, so it's O(n^2).

Comment: Seems to be a lot of discord here. I'm basically going to agree with my gut feeling for the reasons given in the comment of the response bellow, and mark you as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what do you mean by "simple". A divide-by-two search in a sorted array of size n can be written as a non-nested for loop, too, but it would have O(log(n)) time. And like you rightly said, a for loop from 0 to `n*n` would execute in O(`n*n`) time.

Yes, there are codes where running time is not immediately obvious. Even more, there's code out there where the effect and even purpose is not immediately obvious, too :)

Answer (score 2):

If m = n^2, then a "simple for" is certainly linear in m.  If you'd like to argue that this is n^2, please go ahead.

The Big-O notation is counting operations here.    If you're performing n^2 of them, I'm not sure what reporting the sum as n^2 tells you, because you're performing m operations.

Your proposal doesn't make sense to me.  It's misleading about the true name of that sum.  The correct way to say it is O(m).

Comment: It's comparing counting  with the original nested loop function (or any other functions that work on the assumption that n is the base). Otherwise why count complexity at all if i can't compare and know what to focus on?

Comment: @i30817 Algorithmic analysis is about effect of change in n (in your case operations/time, not space).  As n increases, your number of operations increases as n^2.  There could be cases like finding factors where the upper bound of a relatively "simple" loop is related to n like n^.5 or log n, in which case the same effect applies.  I'm not aware of any simple magical way to do algorithm analysis.

Answer (score 1):

It's still O(n) - except that your "n" in this case is "n*n". You've simply increased the value of n - not the complexity of the loop.